# Why $\hat{\mu}_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i}$ converges to $\mu$ a.s.?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. r.v. on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ with distribution $\mu\in\mathcal{M}_{1,c}$, where $\mathcal{M}_{1,c}$ is the space of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support, endow with the weak topology.
Let $$\hat{\mu}_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i}.$$
I know this is a stupid question but why $\hat{\mu}_n$ converges to $\mu$ a.s.? I have to use the law of large numbers?

Comment: Take a look at what $\hat\mu_n((-\infty,z])$ is and see if you can apply LLN there.

Comment: MathLover: my previous answer had a logical mistake (I showed almost sure convergence for each particular $A$ but not almost sure convergence in distribution (over all ‘nice’ $A$)). I’ve now fixed that (I hope…) please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}\newcommand{\B}{\mathscr{B}}\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\pr}{\operatorname{Pr}}$Let $\M:=\M_{1,c}(\Bbb R)$. We have a sequence of measurable $\hat{\mu}_n:\Omega\to\M$ which we may call ‘random measures’.

Fix any event $A\in\B(\Bbb R)$. Define a sequence of random variables $Y_n:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ via $Y_n=\chi_{X_n^{-1}(A)}$. The sequence $(Y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is i.i.d. with common expectation equal to $\mu(A)$.

The set of states $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $\hat{\mu}_n(\omega)(A)\to\mu(A)$ - call this set $\Omega_A$ - is exactly the set of states such that: $$\begin{align}\mu(A)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\delta_{X_j(\omega)}(A)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\chi_A(X_j(\omega))\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nY_j(\omega)\end{align}$$

By the law of large numbers, the above situation happens almost surely, giving $\hat{\mu}_n(A)\to\mu(A)$ almost surely: $\Omega_A$ always contains a subset of full probability.

To show convergence in distribution is also almost sure, we only need to think about this for $A$ of the form $(-\infty,q]$ where $q$ is rational (only need to check for real $q$ that are a point of continuity of $\mu$ sets and because rationals are dense, we may take $q$ to be rational). Because the countable union of null sets is null, it follows that: $$\Omega’:=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\Omega_{(-\infty,q_n]}$$Is an almost sure subset of $\Omega$ (here $(q_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is an enumeration of the rationals).

For $\omega\in\Omega’$ it is then true that $\hat{\mu}_n(\omega)\to\mu$ in $\M$. Therefore $\hat{\mu}_n\to\mu$ almost surely.